# Why do VFS functions get both structs inode and file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

It appears that `struct file` contains a `struct inode *`, yet both are passed to the VFS functions. Why not simply pass `struct file *` alone?

For e.g.  `int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);`

Comment: What functions? `vfs_read` doesn't do that: `vfs_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)`

Comment: to be more specfic, I wnated to know why open() in file_operations structure has both inode and flip.                                                                int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);

Comment: file operation `open()` is hardly used by file systems. see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lki/lki-3.html

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: *for historical reasons*.

They started to remove `struct inode*` from `file_operations` arguments in Linux 2.1 -- i.e. take a look at 2.1.60 commit:

http://repo.or.cz/w/davej-history.git/blobdiff/1018aab0cbe3c20a69685bfa5d217d3535067686..be6cc637f086b24887a11bd4bcc7445220c9b0ff:/include/linux/fs.h

```
@@ -533,9 +534,9 @@ struct super_block {
typedef int (*filldir_t)(void *, const char *, int, off_t, ino_t);

struct file_operations {
-       long long (*llseek) (struct file *, long long, int);
-       long (*read) (struct inode *, struct file *, char *, unsigned long);
-       long (*write) (struct inode *, struct file *, const char *, unsigned long);
+       loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
+       ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
+       ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
        int (*readdir) (struct file *, void *, filldir_t);
        unsigned int (*poll) (struct file *, poll_table *);
        int (*ioctl) (struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
```

I don't know why they didn't do that for `(*open)()` - probably because at the time we open file, initialization of `struct file*` is not completed.

In modern kernel `do_dentry_open()` does that before calling `(*open)()`, so it is rudimentary feature.

Comment: most of the implementation of open() in fie systems do nothing. Only Coda uses to cache the file when they do open()